# Inclusions regarding the limsup and liminf of sets: $ \liminf E_n \subset \limsup E_n $

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{ E_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ be a sequence of sets in some ambient set $\Omega $. I want to show that

$$ \liminf E_n \subset \limsup E_n $$

My attempt: IF $x \in \liminf E_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n \geq k} E_n $, then there is some $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $x \in \bigcap_{n \geq k_0} E_n $. How can I show that $x \in \bigcap_{k =1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n \geq k} E_n = \limsup E_n $ ??

Comment: Remember $\bigcap A_i\subseteq bigcup A_i$

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472519/liminf-e-k-subset-limsup-e-k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $x \in \cap_{n \geq k_0} E_n$. Then

For $1 \leq k \leq k_0$, we have $x \in E_{k_0}$ and hence $x \in \cup_{n \geq k} E_n$.

For $k > k_0$, we have $x \in E_k $ and hence $x \in \cup_{n \geq k} E_n$.

Therefore $x \in \cap_{k \geq 1} \cup_{n \geq k} E_n$.

Comment: Why do you need to consider two cases?

Comment: Because in the two different cases of $k$ we have to consider different $n$ to give evidence of $x \in \cup_{n \geq k} E_n$.

Comment: I dont understand this part. Can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: You are asked to show $x \in \cup_{n \geq k} E_n$ for all $k \geq 1$ given that $x \in E_n$ for all $n \geq k_0$. Fix $k$, you need to find $n \geq k$ such that $x \in E_n$. It is trivial that we can pick $n = k$ for $k > k_0$. For $1 \leq k \leq k_0$, this is also easy, we can pick any $n \geq k_0$. The difference is just that we cannot pick $n = k$ in this case.

Comment: What if we take $n = \max(k,k_0)$. Then we have that $x \in E_n$ for all $n \geq k$ and so for all $n \geq k$, we have $ x \in $ $E_n \subset \bigcup_{n \geq k} E_n $. IS this correct?

Comment: Yes. It is correct and a same but uniform way to pick the $n$.

Comment: Can you give me feedback on my full solution as I wrote it in my own words. thanks very much:
Let $x \in \liminf E_n $. $x \in \bigcap_{n \geq k_0} E_n $ for some $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$. In particular, $x \in E_n$ for all $n \geq k_0 $. Let $k \geq 1$ be arbitrary. We need to find $n \geq k$ so that $x \in E_n $. Take $n = \max \{k,k_0\} $. It follows that $n \geq k$ and $x \in \bigcup_{n \geq k} E_n $. Since $k \geq 1$ was arbitrary, it follows that $x \in \bigcap_{ k \geq 1} \bigcup_{n \geq k} E_n = \limsup E_n $.

Comment: It looks very fine. :)