# What is the name of this theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

In the book [A course in Real Analysis](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Course_in_Real_Analysis.html?id=T-PUyB9YpqcC&source=kp_cover), there is a certain proposition(1.8) that the readers are asked to prove. I wonder what the name of this theorem is. And the theorem is as follows:

*Let* $\Omega$ *be an infinite set and* $\ (a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty} $ *be a sequence of non-empty sets of $\Omega$. Then*
$  \  \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} a_{k}) \subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}a_{k}) $

Comment: Why must it have a name?

Comment: look for limsup and liminf of sets

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472519/is-this-proof-of-liminf-e-k-subset-limsup-e-k-correct

Comment: @RobertIsrael just wanted to reference it. That's all.

Comment: By "sets of $\Omega$", do you mean "subsets of $\Omega$"?

Comment: @J.G. that is correct.